# Receive special char from serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to receive and transmit data with a serial port. I have no problem receiving and transmitting, but I do not see the received data correctly.
If I use a program, ComTestSerial, I see these correct data:

> {STX}1H|\^&|||cobas6000^1|||||host|RSUPL^BATCH|P|1 P|1|||||||U||||||^
>   O|1|        IANNETTA M
>   BIS|0^5016^1^^S1^SC|^^^480^|R||||||N||||1|||||||20191018113556|||F
>   C|1|I|                              ^                         ^^^|G
>   R|1|^^^480/|11|U/L{ETB}A6

But if I use my program in c #, with RicheditText or Texbox, I see this wrong data:

> 2497212492943812412412499111989711554484848944912412412412412410411111511612482838580769466658467721248012449138012449124124124124124124124851241241241241241249413791244912432323232323232327365787869848465327732667383124489453484954944994948349948367124949494525648941248212412412412412412478124124124124491241241241241241241245048495749484956494951535354124124124701367124491247312432323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323294323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232329494941247113821244912494949452564847124494912485477623655413104.

I use this simple code (written by a colleague) to receive:

```
string cMsg = "";
while (this.ComPort.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    int nChar = this.ComPort.ReadChar();
    cMsg += nChar.ToString();
}
Thread.Sleep(100);
return cMsg;
```

Which reads data from a serial connection that works perfectly.
What could be the problem?

Comment: This seems to be an encoding issue. What encoding of the received data stream does ComTestSerial expect? Use the same when reading the chars.

Comment: I don't know the encoding that that program uses, how can I know and modify my encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting a number to a string, so, say, when `nChar` is 2, the output will be a string `"2"`, and when `nChar` is 49, the output will be `"49"`.

So, the message begins with `{STX}1`. `{STX}` is an ASCII control code 2, and `1` is ASCII code 49. Thus the "wrong data" begins with `"249"`.

Thus, the data isn't wrong, and the code does exactly what you told it to, except that your colleague didn't mean what you intended :)

Instead of converting ASCII codes to strings, convert them to characters, and also use a stringbuilder to minimize the number of times the string is resized.

```
StringBuilder message(ComPort.BytesToRead);

while (ComPort.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    message.Append((char)ComPort.ReadChar());
}
return message.ToString();
```

But you don't need to do any of it! `SerialPort.ReadExisting` does what you want:

`return ComPort.ReadExisting();`.

Stylistic note: C# is not Java, and littering the code with `this.` is not idiomatic nor necessary. Don't do it unless there's a good reason to.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I changed the code like you said and it still works.
For the use of this, as I have already said, I didn't write that code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems that you are getting an integer from your port, and when you are using  ToString() you just write a number to string

```
int nChar = this.ComPort.ReadChar();
cMsg += nChar.ToString();
```

This integer should be A 21-bit Unicode code point. 
So you just can use Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32) Method, it will convert integer to the actual character: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=netframework-4.8

Your full code should then look like this:

```
string cMsg = "";
while (this.ComPort.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    int nChar = this.ComPort.ReadChar();
    cMsg += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(nChar);
}
Thread.Sleep(100);
return cMsg;
```

Comment: Works fine! You'r great! Thanks!

Comment: `char` is implicitly a UTF-16 codepoint, so manual conversion is unnecessary.